# How to order a table desc when you have a column name "date"?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g, sql-order-by

I can't figure this out.

I have the following table: SQL_LOG {ID, DATE, MACHINE, TXT};

I want to make a SELECT statement to see all the logs ordered by the date, so I wrote:

```
SELECT *
FROM SQL_LOG
ORDER BY DATE desc;
```

I get the following error:

```
ORA-00936: missing expression
00936. 00000 -  "missing expression"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Error at Line: 3 Column: 10
```

Comment: Can you post your complete query?

Answer (score 1):

`date` is a SQL keyword (a data type) and a reserved word in Oracle.  My advice is to change the name of the column.  However, you can also escape the name:

```
order by "DATE"
```

Note that when escaping a column name, the case of letter is important, so `"DATE"` is different from `"date"`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this `select * from SQL_LOG order by "DATE" desc;`